# HTML5 Canvas - Draw an annular sector

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, donut-chart

I would like to draw edges of a game map (10000x10000) with an annular shape (so the map would be round). The simplest (but the worst in term of performance) way is to draw a filling circle (radius of 6000) and an unfilling circle (radius of 5000).

The player has a small viewport, then it is not necessary to draw a whole annular. A sector is fine.

I tried with ctx.arc, but it gives me a chord...

is there an efficient way to draw a huge **annular sector** on canvas2D ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shape is a stroked arc:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var strokewidth=100;
var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var PI=Math.PI;
var radius=Math.min(cw,ch)/2-strokewidth/2;
ctx.lineWidth=strokewidth;
ctx.lineCap='butt';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,-PI*3/4,-PI/16);
ctx.strokeStyle='mediumVioletRed';
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=378 height=378></canvas>
```

An Aside: Redrawing a 10K x 10K canvas will be your main (and huge) performance hit. You probably should refactor your design to avoid extremely large canvases.

Comment: just to point out you forgot to include `ctx.lineCap = "butt";` . Canvas `lineCap` state may be `round` or `square` the result will not be what is wanted.

Comment: @Blindman67. Good point. Even though "butt" is the default there's a possibility the current `lineCap` is not at default. Thanks for the 2nd pair of eyes. :-)